# Is my downspout frozen/ what can i do

Tags: downspout

I believe my downspout is frozen, it runs across the side of my house.  There is a little bit of water on the front of my house below the gutters and roof, which I am not sure where it came from.  Is this issue one I should be worried about, or will it work itself out with the thawing?[image]

Comment: It's hard to say by just looking at the picture. It depends on where that water is originating. It appears from the pic that there may be some water running over the edge of the gutter above the left window frame. In that case it probably isn't a big deal. If the water is coming out from under the eave near the house, it could be a problem caused by an ice dam, inadequate drip edge or some other roofing issue.